# CentOS Apache VirtualHost default

Tags: apache, centos7, virtual-hosts

I have set up some virtal host to distinguish between my subdomains (/etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf).

This was working on my old server (Debian 7). But now if I browse the root page I get the first defined VirtualHost displayed.

Also if I am browsing an undefined subdomain I get the first VirtualHost config displayed.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@example.com

    ServerName sub1.example.com
    ServerAlias sub1.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/sub/sub_sub1/www
    ServerAdmin Admin
    CustomLog /home/sub/sub_sub1/logs/access.log combined
    ErrorLog /home/sub/sub_sub1/logs/error.log
    LogLevel warn

    <Directory /home/sub/sub_sub1/www>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first defined VirtualHost will serve all the requests that don't get handled by the other ones. You can create a default VirtualHost that handles those requests. To make sure this VirtualHost is the first one, you should name its config-file something like "000-default.conf".

This might also help you: [VirtualHost Examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: omg. Yes I have overlooked that file in the old config. There is an 000-default.conf too. Thanks